# Open and scan dms for key words

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm working on a bot, and wanted to know if there was a way to open dms from all people in a server, and see if any commands were in there. If so I want the commands to be completed, but only with certain key words. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the `Guild`'s `members` collection and access the `GuildMember`'s `DMchannel` using `GuildMember.user.dmChannel` then fetch all the messages using `dmChannel.messages.fetch()` then use `filter()` to get the messages with the keywords you're looking for

```js
message.guild.members.cache.forEach(async (member) => { 
  const fetchedMsgs = await member.user.dmChannel.messages.fetch()
  const messages = fetchedMsgs.filter((message) => message.content.toLowerCase().includes('search term')) // make sure the search term is lowercase
  messages.forEach((message) => console.log(`${message.author.username} (${message.author.id}): '${message.content}' @ ${message.createdAt}`)
})
```